# How to randomly insert characters in a String using insert method

Tags: java, string, random

I'm doing a project and I need to develop a Class or method that puts randomly characters into a `String`

I insert a `String` via `Scanner`.

I was thinking using the library *java.lang.StringBuilder* and then using the `insert()`.But I don´t know if that works because the method needs also read the empty space and doesn't do anything and move to the next word.

Like: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();` `sb.insrt();`

Eg:

Input: "Hello World"

Output: "**H**E**E**J**L**R**L**Q**O** **W**N**O**V**R**B**L**Y**D**"

(I put the Letter in Bold from the original Word)

In this case, i need that the program insert random character in x+1, in other words, read the first letter skip and the second position he puts a random letter and so on and so on..

Comment: String has an insert method? That's news to me.

Comment: Just a side note: strings are immutable in Java. You need to create a new one by concatenation or use `StringBuider` or `StringBuffer`which both are mutable and basically share the same API (The  `StringBuffer`is synchronized and the "thread-safe)

Comment: Yes, sorry it is StringBuild that has the method insert.

Comment: @Francisco Then please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you capitalised the characters from the original string, I'll ignore that in my answer.

You should first select your range of letters, say a-z or A-Z (note the capitalisation). Then - create a random range -- something like the following code:

```
Random rn = new Random();
int minimum = 97; // the byte code of ASCII 'a'
int n = 26; //Letters in the ABC

String newString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < oldString.length; i++){
    int k = rn.nextInt(n);
    randomNum =  minimum + k;
    newString += oldString.charAt(i);
    newString += (char)randomNum;
 }
```

This will give you a random a-z

- this code will also place a random letter AFTER the original string, but I'm sure you can handle that

Answer (score 0):

You can input whole string with one string and store the output with another like this

```
Random random = new Random();
String input,output = "";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
input = sc.nextLine();
for(int i = 0; i<input.length(); i++){
  output += input.charAt(i);
  output += (char)(random.nextInt(25) + 97); // Random Character 'a to z'
}
System.out.println(output);
```

in `for` loop we first concate character of `input` of given index `i`.
Then we generate a random number (which range from 97 to 122) and cast them to `char` (a to z) and concate them in output.